# Find out what process is trying to initiate a connection in Windows

Tags: windows, firewalls, tcp

I'm not trying to find established TCP connections. I have a Windows 2008 R2 server and my host-based L3 firewall is showing one TCP connection ATTEMPT to a remote address. The connection is not established as the servers are not allowed to communicate on the gateway firewall. What's the easiest and non-obtrusive way to find out this process? I cannot install sniffing tools like Wireshark on this server due to security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your access restrictions, you can do this:

1. `Task Manager` > `View` > `Select Columns` > `PID`
2. `netstat -ano | find "127.0.0.1"` (put whatever IP you want in the quotes)
3. Compare `PID` to active `connections`.

More information on how to use *[`find`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_%28command%29)*, and *[`netstat`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netstat)*

Comment: What about `netstat -ano 1 | find "remote address"`?

Comment: `1` means it's refreshing every second. If you want to do that, sure. Here's more info on [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_%28command%29).